# xcode: Custom Button "blocks" touch for Objects underneath it

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I´ve got a button like:

```
UIButton *btnNotification=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnNotification.frame=CGRectMake(130,80,120,40);
[btnNotification addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:btnNotification];
```

So as you can see it´s a "invisible" button.
The Problem is I´ve got a slider underneath this button and when touch both only the button OR the slider gets triggered. But I would like to trigger both: The button should fire an event and by dragging further the slider should update its value as well. How is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds messy. Can't you do everything you want from the slider and dump this "notification button"?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @Droppy, UISlider inherits from UIView which means you can add a touch gesture to it. try using this instead of the "invisible" button.